# Override mixin's watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

As you can see in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/got2Lmnh/), I have a global mixin with a `value` data and a watcher on this data :

```
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
    return {
        value: 'test',
      mixinWatcher: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
        handler() {
        console.log('mixin');
        this.mixinWatcher = true;
      },
        immediate: true,
    },
  },
});
```

I also have two components :

- `NoMergeComponent` that doesn't have any watcher. I want this component to use the default watcher;
- `MergeComponent` that's supposed to override the default watcher.

Is it possible to override the mixin's watcher or am I supposed to find another way, such as removing manually the watcher ?

I also think that I can workaround this issue by binding a method to the watcher, and override this method instead of the entire watcher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The workaround works.](https://jsfiddle.net/ThomasFerro/xj4dchxu/)

I basically call another method in the watcher, and I can simply let *Vue.js* do the merge when I want to override this method :

Here's my mixin :

```
Vue.mixin({
    data() {
    return {
        value: 'test',
      mixinWatcher: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
        handler() {
        this.valueWatcher();
      },
        immediate: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    valueWatcher() {
        console.log('mixin');
      this.mixinWatcher = true;
    }
  },
});
```

And the component that needs to override the watcher's method :

```
const MergeComponent = {
    template: '#test-component-template',
  methods: {
    valueWatcher() {
        console.log('component');
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i had a similar problem recently with overriding watchers defined in mixin in component using class-style components. i am sharing this solution that works for me.
the mixin code:

```
@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue{
    value: string = '';
    @Watch('value')
    onValueChanged(newVal: string, oldVal: string){
        console.log('MIXIN');
    }
}
```

the component code:

```
@Component
export default  class  MyComponent extends Mixins(MyMixin){

    onValueChanged(newVal: string, oldVal: string){
        console.log('COMPONENT');
    }
}
```

running this code on value changed the result in console will be: 'COMPONENT'.
as you see removing @Watch in component got me to my goal.